# Replace a UTF-8 character in R

Tags: r, utf-8

I have an R "plugin" that reads a bunch of lines from stdin, parses it and evaluates it.

```
...
code <- readLines(f, warn=F)   ## that's where the lines come from...
result <- eval(parse(text=code))
...
```

Now, sometimes the system that provides the lines of code kindly inserts a UTF-8 non-break space (`U+00A0` = `\xc2\xa0`) here and there in the code. The `parse()` chokes on such characters. Example:

```
s <- "1 +\xc2\xa03"
s
[1] "1 + 3"   ## looks fine doesn't it? In fact, the Unicode "NON-BREAK SPACE" is there

eval(parse(text=s))
Error in parse(text = s) : <text>:1:4: unexpected input
1: 1 +?
      ^

eval(parse(text=gsub("\xc2\xa0"," ",s)))
[1] 4
```

I would like to replace that character with a regular space, and can do so (but at my own peril, I guess) as above with this:

```
code <- gsub('\xc2\xa0',' ',code)
```

However, this is not clean as the byte sequence `'\xc2\a0'` could conceivably start matching in the middle of another 2-byte char whose 2nd byte is `0xc2`.

Perhaps a bit better, we can say:

```
code <- gsub(intToUtf8(0x00a0L),' ',code)
```

But this would not generalize to a UTF-8 string.

Surely there is a better, more expressive way to enter a string containing some UTF-8 characters?  In general, what's the right way to express a UTF-8 string (here, the pattern argument of `sub()`)?

---

**Edit**: to be clear, I am interested in entering UTF-8 chars in a String by specifying their hexadecimal value. Consider the following example (note that `"é"` is Unicode `U+00E9` and can be expressed in UTF-8 as `0xc3a9`):

```
s <- "Cet été."
gsub("té","__",s)
# --> "Cet é__."
# works, but I like to keep my code itself free of UTF-8 literals,
# plus, for the initial question, I really don't want to enter an actual
# UTF-8 "NON BREAKABLE SPACE" in my code as it would be undistinguishable
# from a regular space.

gsub("t\xc3\xa9","__",s)  ## works, but I question how standard and portable
# --> "Cet é__."

gsub("t\\xc3\\xa9","__",s)  ## doesn't work
# --> "Cet été."

gsub("t\x{c3a9}","__",s)  ## would work in Perl, doesn't seem to work in R
# Error: '\x' used without hex digits in character string starting "s\x"
```

Answer (score 2):

(Earlier stuff deleted.)

EDIT2:

```
> s <- '\U00A0'
> s
[1] " "
> code <- gsub(s, '__','\xc2\xa0' )
> code
[1] "__"
```

Comment: Why do you think that should work?  `"\\xc2"` is a literal slash followed by `"xc2"`, hardly the hex sequence I'm trying to form. In Java, yes, because there is an interpolation of the String done first by the compiler, then, say, `Pattern.compile()` further interprets the String.  But here, no. I also edited my question to try and make it clearer with another example. The `"\\x<hex>"` clearly doesn't work.

Comment: I think it should work ... because I tested it. The pattern "\\xc2" matches the `\xc2` character.

Comment: It doesn't, the `\x{c2a0}` is simply passed through, but since it represents Unicode's "NON-BREAK SPACE", you just don't see it in the display. Proof: `gsub("\xc2\xa0","__",gsub("\\xc2\\xa0", " ", "other\xc2\xa0stuff"))` returns: `[1] "other__stuff"`.

Comment: Thanks! EDIT2 contains exactly what I was looking for ('\Uhhhh' to enter a unicode char). Now, can we please clean up what's before EDIT2?...

Comment: I admit to a lingering puzzlement about why this _should_ work. I simply took you at your word that `\U00A0` would equal `\xc2\xa0` whereas I would have expected it to equal `\UC2A0`.

Comment: Indeed, Unicode `U+00A0` is expressed in UTF-8 as `\x{c2a0}` (Perl) or `\xc2\xa0`, as I said. See http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

Comment: My expectations were being met by the UTF-16 value.